# Free a linked list

Tags: c, memory-leaks, linked-list, valgrind, free

I have problems freeing my linked list correctly. I don't really know, how to make it with head and current...

```
typedef struct list{
   int info;
   struct list *link;
} Node;

Node *_getnode (){
    return((Node *) malloc (sizeof (Node)));
}

int main() {

    Node *s = _getnode();
    s -> link = NULL;
    Node *t = s;
    int c;

    while (1) {
        printf("\n\t Enter number : ");
        scanf ("%d", &s -> info);   

        printf ("\n\t Continue? ");
        __fpurge (stdin);
        c = getchar ();

        if (c == 'N' || c == 'n'){
            s -> link = NULL;
            break;
        }

        s -> link = _getnode ();
        s = s -> link;
    }

    s = t;

    free(s);
    free(t);

    putchar('\n');
    return (0);
}
```

When I enter just one number, than valgrind says, there's no memory leak. But otherwise there is. I understand, that I have to free more than just the fist node, but I don't know how.

Comment: Not a good idea to use `__fpurge` - it is not portable etc. The double underscore is a give away

Comment: Do not cast the return value of `malloc()`. You need to free each node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, the lines

```
free(s);
free(t);
```

are redundant as you've already assigned `s = t;` in the previous line.

The memory leak occurs because you're only using `free` on the head pointer, not all the nodes in the linked list. So ideally, you should loop through all the nodes and free the memory allocated to each node, here is what your code should look like :

```
while(s != NULL)
{
     t = s->link;
     free(s);
     s = t;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
void free_list(Node *head)
{
    Node *s;
    Node *n;
    if (head == NULL) /* passing `NULL' should be ok */
        return;
    for (s = head ; s != NULL ; s = n)
    {
        n = s->link;
        free(s);
    }
 }
```

you can see an obvious flaw in the way you create your list.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, please initialize the node so that the program can tell the end of list correctly.

```
Node *_getnode (){
    Node* buffer = malloc (sizeof (Node));
    if (buffer == NULL) exit(1);
    buffer->info = 0; /* not important */
    buffer->link = NULL; /* this is important */
    return buffer;
}
```

Then, free the nodes one by one.

```
void free_nodes (Node* head){
    while(head != NULL){
        Node* next = head->link;
        free(head);
        head = next;
    }
}
```

Not tested, passing `t` to this `free_nodes` should work.

Comment: Thank you for advide. Edited.